# Propel not adding single quote to fields name in MySql query

Tags: php, mysql, database, orm, propel

I have the following mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE `content_segments`
(
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `include` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    `dimension` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `media_type` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `match` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `content` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

The problem is the **match** field is reserved word in MySQL, and propel2 doesn't surround the fields name with a single quote to escape the reserved word at run-time (when the query is generated).
I wonder if there's a why to force propel escaping all my table fields with single quote to avoid reserved words errors.
The error I'm getting is this:

```
Unable to execute SELECT statement [SELECT id, include, dimension, media_type, match, content FROM content_segments WHERE id = :p0]
```

Comment: *"escaping all my table fields with single quote"* - You mean ticks `\`` not "quotes" `'` or `"`.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know anything about Propel. A quick fix would be to use another word for it, such as `matches` and staying away from reserved words if at all possible.

Comment: I thought about this, but it's a legacy table, it's hard to change the field name without breaking to existing code.

Comment: I understand. Well, let's see if anyone else picks up on the question and hopefully provide a solution for you.

Comment: this seems to be a known Propel issue [705](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/issues/705) and Propel2 [781](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/issues/781)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is in the issue discussion on propel git repository.

> We have changed the way how identifier quoting is working. You need to
>   activate it per database or per table:

```
<database ... identifierQuoting="true">
or
<table ... identifierQuoting="true">
```

As it was stated in the comment of the question, the related propel issue is https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/issues/781 for propel2